# Mac OS： Shortcut for restoring a minimized window?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

I've managed to find or set shortcuts for "zoom" and "maximize" a window, but I can't find the way to restore a minized window, other than click the icon in the dock. Is there a way to set a shortcut for this manuever?

Comment: same issue here... someone help!

Answer (score 20):

Here you go https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55440:

> 1. <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> until you get the app's icon.
> 2. **Before releasing** <kbd>Command</kbd>, press and hold <kbd>**⌥**</kbd> (option).

Comment: Still working in Big Sur OS

Comment: I don't see why not just do it like windows cmd+tab and that's it